# Docusign Transform Pdf Fields For single recipient?

Tags: docusignapi, envelope

I created an envelope in DocuSign where one of the documents contains transform PDF fields. This envelope is sent to multiple recipients and those transform PDF fields are editable by all of them.

I'm wondering if there's a way to only allow for one recipient to edit transform PDF fields rather than allowing all recipients the ability to edit the transform PDF fields using the DocuSign API.

Answer (score 2):

In the "Create Envelope" API request, set the **defaultRecipient** property to **true** for the Recipient that you want to 'own' the transformed PDF fields.  Here's an example request showing how to set the **defaultRecipient** property:

```
POST https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/ACCOUNT_NUMBER/envelopes HTTP/1.1

X-DocuSign-Authentication: {"Username":"USER_NAME","Password":"PASSWORD","IntegratorKey":"INTEGRATOR_KEY"}
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=MY_BOUNDARY
Accept: application/json
Host: demo.docusign.net
Content-Length: 59549

--MY_BOUNDARY
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Disposition: form-data

{
    "emailBlurb":"Test Email Body",
    "emailSubject": "Test Email Subject",
    "status" : "sent",
    "compositeTemplates": [
    {
        "inlineTemplates": [
        {
            "sequence" : 1,
            "recipients": {
                "signers" : [{
                    "email": "sallysemail@outlook.com",
                    "name": "Sally Adamson",
                    "recipientId": "1",
                    "defaultRecipient": "true"
                }]
            }
        }],
        "document": {
            "documentId": 1,
            "name": "Customer Agreement",
            "transformPdfFields": "true"
        }
    }]
}

--MY_BOUNDARY
Content-Type: application/pdf
Content-Disposition: file; filename="SampleForm.pdf"; documentid="1"

<document bytes removed>

--MY_BOUNDARY--
```

Comment: Thank you, saved me hours of trying. and finally it worked. The documentation is ridiculously misleading.