# Docusign signhere tabs not appearing on the document for signing

Tags: docusignapi

I am new to docusign. I am using docusign composite template to sign a document by a few signers. But when i created the envelope using the api envelope is getting created and recipients receives emails  to sign the document.

But when the recipients open the document to sign, there is no sign here tab. I am kind follow the suggestions  given here [Docusign Transform Pdf Fields For multiple recipients?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24189713/docusign-transform-pdf-fields-for-multiple-recipients) but didnot work. My sample code.

Any help is highly appreciated

```
 private EnvelopeDefinition makeEnvelope() throws Exception {
    
    final List<SignerData> signersList = new ArrayList<>();
    signersList.add(new SignerData("xxxxxx@xxxxx.com", "xxxx zzzz", "PrimarySigner\\*"));
    signersList.add(new SignerData("xxxx.kxxx@xxx.com", "aaaa bbbb", "SecondarySigner\\*"));
    int recipientId = 0;
    final List<Signer> signers = new ArrayList<>();
    for (final SignerData signerData : signersList) {
        final Signer signer = new Signer();
        signer.setEmail(signerData.getEmail());
        signer.setName(signerData.getName());
        signer.recipientId(++recipientId + "");
        
        final SignHere signHere = new SignHere();
        signHere.setTabLabel(signerData.getAnchorString());

        final Tabs tabs = new Tabs();
        tabs.setSignHereTabs(Arrays.asList(signHere));
        signer.setTabs(tabs);

        signers.add(signer);
    }

    final Recipients recipients = new Recipients();
    recipients.setSigners(signers);

    final List<InlineTemplate> inlineTemplates = new ArrayList<>();
    final InlineTemplate inlineTemplate = new InlineTemplate();

    inlineTemplate.sequence("1");
    inlineTemplate.setRecipients(recipients);
    inlineTemplates.add(inlineTemplate);

    final Document doc = createDocumentFromFile(filename, docName, "3");

    final CompositeTemplate compositeTemplate = new CompositeTemplate();
    compositeTemplate.setInlineTemplates(inlineTemplates);
    compositeTemplate.compositeTemplateId("1");
    compositeTemplate.setDocument(doc);


    final EnvelopeDefinition envelopeDefinition = new EnvelopeDefinition();
    envelopeDefinition.setEmailSubject("Please sign this " + docName + ".");
    envelopeDefinition.setEmailBlurb("This is a very confidential document.");
    envelopeDefinition.setCompositeTemplates(Arrays.asList(compositeTemplate));
    //envelopeDefinition.setDocuments(Arrays.asList(doc));
    envelopeDefinition.setStatus(ENVELOPE_STATUS_SENT);
    //envelopeDefinition.setRecipients(recipients);
    return envelopeDefinition;
}

private Document createDocumentFromFile(final String fileName, final String docName, final String docId) throws Exception {
    final byte[] buffer = getFileContentInBytes(fileName);
    final String extention = fileName.split("\\.")[1];
    return createDocument(buffer, docName, extention, docId);
}

private Document createDocument(final byte[] data, final String documentName, final String fileExtention, final String documentId) {
    final Document document = new Document();
    document.setDocumentBase64(Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(data));
    document.setName(documentName);
    document.setFileExtension(fileExtention);
    document.setDocumentId(documentId);
    document.setTransformPdfFields("true");
    return document;
}
```

**UPDATE**
I updated my code and removed Composite Template but still the *Signhere* tab is not displayed. I have used pdf form fields and kept their name in sync with the tab label but still the *signhere* box didnt appear. Am i missing somthing?

```
Changed the code ` private EnvelopeDefinition makeEnvelope( ) throws Exception {
    final List<SignerData> signersList = new ArrayList<>();
    
    //Tab labels is Owner1DocuSignSignHere Owner2DocuSignSignHere Owner3DocuSignSignHere are the fields present in my PDF file
    signersList.add(new SignerData("aaaaaaaa@xxxx.com", "aaaa bbbbb", "Owner1DocuSignSignHere"));
    signersList.add(new SignerData("bbbbbbb@xxxxxx.com", "ccccc ddddd", "Owner2DocuSignSignHere"));
    signersList.add(new SignerData("ssssss@xxxxx.in", "eeee eeee", "Owner3DocuSignSignHere"));

    int recipientId = 0;
    final List<Signer> signers = new ArrayList<>();
    for (final SignerData signerData : signersList) {
        final Signer signer = new Signer();
        signer.setEmail(signerData.getEmail());
        signer.setName(signerData.getName());
        signer.recipientId(++recipientId + "");

        final SignHere signHere = new SignHere();
        signHere.setTabLabel(signerData.getTabLabel()); 

        final Tabs tabs = new Tabs();
        tabs.setSignHereTabs(Arrays.asList(signHere));
        signer.setTabs(tabs);

        signers.add(signer);
    }

    final Recipients recipients = new Recipients();
    recipients.setSigners(signers);

    final Document doc = createDocumentFromFile(filename, docName, "4");

    final EnvelopeDefinition envelopeDefinition = new EnvelopeDefinition();
    envelopeDefinition.setEmailSubject("Please sign this " + docName + ".");
    envelopeDefinition.setEmailBlurb("This is a very confidential document.");
    envelopeDefinition.setDocuments(Arrays.asList(doc));
    envelopeDefinition.setStatus(ENVELOPE_STATUS_SENT);
    envelopeDefinition.setRecipients(recipients);
    return envelopeDefinition;
}

private Document createDocumentFromFile(final String fileName, final String docName, final String docId) throws Exception {
    final byte[] buffer = getFileContentInBytes(fileName);
    final String extention = fileName.split("\\.")[1];
    return createDocument(buffer, docName, extention, docId);
}

private Document createDocument(final byte[] data, final String documentName, final String fileExtention, final String documentId) {
    final Document document = new Document();
    document.setDocumentBase64(Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(data));
    document.setName(documentName);
    document.setFileExtension(fileExtention);
    document.setDocumentId(documentId);
    document.setTransformPdfFields("true");
    return document;
}
```

`

Comment: If you provide your documents, recipients and tabs from your code - what's the template doing? why do you need a template?

Comment: @InbarGazit i have updated my implementaion as you said but still the signhere field is not appearing

Answer (score 1):

You are missing positioning information for your `signHere` object.
You can do it in two ways. Using anchor strings:

```
signHere.setAnchorString("text");
signHere.setAnchorUnits("pixels");
signHere.setAnchorYOffset(String.valueOf(50));
signHere.setAnchorXOffset(String.valueOf(50));
```

Or you can use fixed positioning and then you have to specificy not only `XPosition` and `YPosition` but also `DocumentId` and `PageId` numbers.

Comment: Thank you,  But i do not want to use the anchorString.                                                                   Let me share you my scenario.                                                                                                      I have a PDF form that has Text fields with name in the format Owner1DocuSignSignHere. When I hit the envelope api with the pdf document,                      Can it be possible to place signhere tabs where it finds a form field with name Owner1DocuSignSignHere

Comment: is "Owner1DocuSignSignHere" an actual text that is on the document? then it can be used as anchorString. Not clear.

Comment: No, We have a text field with name Owner1DocuSignSignHere

Comment: OK, so why you do not want to use an anchorString?

Comment: Yes, So can it be possible with pdf fields without using templates?

Comment: Yes, but not sure exactly what you mean by "pdf fields". Do you mean the original PDF had meta-data about where to place signing elements (tabs)?

Comment: I have a PDF form that has Text fields with name in the format Owner1DocuSignSignHere. When I hit the envelope api with the pdf document, Can it be possible to place signhere tabs where it finds a form field with name Owner1DocuSignSignHere

Comment: is this text visible on the document? ("Owner1DocuSignSignHere") or you talking metadata?

Comment: No the text field name is not visible in the document

Comment: OK, so I think what you need is PDF Form Fields. Before trying this with the API, you will want to make sure it works from the web UI.

Comment: https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/ndse-user-guide-send-a-pdf-with-form-fields follow this article and make sure it's working first. If this won't work - it won't work from API. Once you got this working, you can use API logging to see how it was done.