# Embedded Signing of PDF Document with Form Fields

Tags: docusignapi

The scenario that I am currently dealing with is as follows:

We have an application that pre-fills much of a PDF document's form fields with user data (think name, address, etc).

Additionally, there are form fields which have been named according to the details specified at: https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#REST%20API%20References/Document%20Parameters.htm#Transfor

For example, one of the form fields might be named "first_name" and populated with a value of "John", while another field is empty and named "eSignSignHere" (to be used for DocuSign signing).

When creating the envelope, the JSON payload looks something like what follows, submitted with an HTTP POST to `[baseUrl]/envelopes` as a multipart request, PDF included.

```
{
  "emailSubject": "Test PDF Field Transform",
  "documents": [
    {
      "documentId": 1,
      "name": "fillable-form.pdf",
      "transformPdfFields": "true"
    }
  ],
  "recipients": {
    "signers": [
      {
        "email": "email@email.com",
        "name": "John Smith",
        "recipientId": "1234",
        "clientUserId": "1234",
        "defaultRecipient": "true"
      }
    ]
  },
  "status": "sent"
}
```

As expected, in response, I receive an envelope ID & URI.

When fetching that envelope by ID, however (using `[baseUrl]/envelopes/[envelopeId]/views/recipient`), I see the Free-form signing view, with none of the fields displayed, but rather the field toolbox, allowing the user to drop fields & signatures where they'd like.

Ultimately, I'd like the same behavior as what occurs when a document is uploaded via the web console, selecting "Assign fields".

Is it possible to do this or is the only option when uploading a document to free-form sign?  If the latter, what is the purpose of the transformPdfFields property in this context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After more searching, I stumbled upon [Docusign Transform Pdf Fields For single recipient?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20053160/docusign-transform-pdf-fields-for-single-recipient).

Altering the original JSON payload slightly, yielded the result I was after.
The adjusted JSON, submitted along in the multipart request with the PDF document is now:

```
{
  "emailSubject": "Test PDF Field Transform",
  "compositeTemplates": [
    {
      "inlineTemplates": [
        {
          "sequence": 1,
          "recipients": {
            "signers": [
              {
                "email": "email@email.com",
                "name": "John Smith",
                "recipientId": "1234",
                "clientUserId": "1234",
                "defaultRecipient": "true"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ],
      "document": {
        "documentId": 1,
        "name": "fillable-form.pdf",
        "transformPdfFields": "true"
      }
    }
  ],
  "status": "sent"
}
```

For the purpose of displaying the transformed PDF fields, rather than free-form mode – this works just as expected.

Comment: Thank you for posting the answer, much appreciated.