# DocuSign Transform PDF field to initialHereTab

Tags: docusignapi

I have seen how to transform a PDF signature field into a signHereTab from the following other questions:

[Docusign Transform Pdf Fields For multiple recipients?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24189713/docusign-transform-pdf-fields-for-multiple-recipients)

[Docusign Transform Pdf Fields For single recipient?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20053160/docusign-transform-pdf-fields-for-single-recipient)

However, I haven't been able to transform a PDF signature field into the initialHereTab. What PDF form field is needed to have it transformed into the initialHereTab?

Below is an HTTP request (created in Postman) that I've tried. It includes the base64 of a test PDF that has 4 fields in it. It ends up with signHereTab controls in both Signer1Signature and Signer1Initial form fields.

1. Signer1Name - text field for name
2. Signer1Email - text field for email
3. Signer1Signature - signature field for signature
4. Signer1Initial - signature field for initials

HTTP Post body:

```
--AAA
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Disposition: form-data

{
  "emailBlurb": "Test for PDF Form Fields",
  "emailSubject": "Test for PDF Form Fields",
  "status": "sent",
  "compositeTemplates": [{
    "inlineTemplates": [{
      "sequence": "1",
      "recipients": {
        "signers": [{
          "recipientId": "1",
          "name": "[replace with name]",
          "email": "[replace with email]",                  
          "defaultRecipient": "true",
          "tabs":{
             "textTabs":[
                {
                   "tabLabel":"Signer1\\*",
                }
             ],
             "checkboxTabs":[
                {
                   "tabLabel":"Signer1\\*",
                   "selected":true
                }
             ],
             "signHereTabs":[
                {
                   "tabLabel":"Signer1Signature\\*"
                }
             ],
             "initialHereTabs":[
                {
                    "tabLabel":"Signer1Initial\\*"
                }
             ],
             "dateSignedTabs":[
                {
                   "tabLabel":"Signer1\\*"
                }
             ],
             "radioGroupTabs":[
                {
                   "groupName":"Signer1\\*",
                   "radios":[
                      {
                         "value":"M",
                         "selected":true
                      }
                   ]
                }
             ]
          }          
        }]
      }
    }],
    "document": {
      "documentId": "1",
      "name": "S.pdf",
      "transformPdfFields": "true"
    }

  }]
}

--AAA
Content-Type: application/pdf
Content-Disposition: file; filename="f4506t.pdf"; documentid=1
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
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--AAA--
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PDF Form Fields that contain `DocuSignInitialHere` or `eSignInitialHere` will be converted to a DocuSign `Initials` field/tab.

[The documentation for the conversion rules is in composite templates info.](https://www.docusign.com/p/APIGuide/Content/Sending%20Group/Rules%20for%20CompositeTemplate%20Usage.htm) I'll request that it be added to the PDF Forms Transformation docs too.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance. I hadn't found that documentation yet!